# Add a RowNumber to a list of Dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
[
    {"new": "item"},
    {"from": "here"}
]
```

Is there a one-liner I can do to add in the index position of that item, for example so it ends up as:

```
[
    {"idx": 0, "new": "item"},
    {"idx": 1, "from": "here"}
]
```

Note: I'd also like to make sure the position of the `idx` is at the start (dict ordering supported in python3).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
data = [
    {"new": "item"},
    {"from": "here"}
]

result = [{ **e, "idx" : i } for i, e in enumerate(data)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'idx': 0, 'new': 'item'}, {'from': 'here', 'idx': 1}]
```

Comment: in python3 this would add it to the end of the index, any way to get the `index` at the start?

Comment: @DavidL Try: `{ "idx" : i,  **e }`?

Answer (score 2):

A oneliner recreates the dictionary - that is very wasteful - lots of time/memory etc needed to allocate and create the new dict. It is better to simply iterate your list of dictionaries and add the index key-value pair:

```
k = [ {"new": "item"}, {"from": "here"}]

for i,d in enumerate(k):
    d["idx"] = i 

print(k)
```

Output:

```
[{'new': 'item', 'idx': 0}, {'from': 'here', 'idx': 1}]
```

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean by 'wasteful' ? Does it take up a lot more time/memory, or what do you mean exactly?

Comment: thanks for the update. Is it possible to push it to the first position though? I'd like to `idx` column to be the first column.

Comment: Think a list of 100 dicts, each with 10 key/value entries - the oneliner would create a new list, instantiate 100 new dicts, create 10 key/values in each ... to (in total) add 100 new keys in total ... if you remove the name of the source-list python can release the ressources for that .. but still - you need to instantiate a lot of stuff for just 1 new value per dict.

Comment: dicts are input-ordered (3.7 / 3.6 IPython) - the only way to reorder a key is to recreate the full dict sorted as you like